# Good profiling methods for spring applications on Java EE server

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, profiling, websphere

I am intressted in methods to do (non intrusive) performance profiling in a Spring application deployed in a Java EE server. In my case I use WebSphere Application Server 7, WebSphere MQ 7 and OpenJPA/IBM DB2.

I only need a brief overview of potential bottlenecks etc. I could always log time stamps and do some analysis, but if you guys have any best practice, I am listening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the **VisualVM profiler**. It ships with modern Sun/Oracle JDKs (`bin/jvisualvm.exe`) and is able to connect to running java instances.

More information can be found here: http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html

Comment: You got to do a bit of extra work to get the VisualVM to connect to an IBM JDK. Here is some info if you are heading down that path - http://jcraane.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/monitoring-ibm-jvm-with-visualvm.html